# Is there a way to use Xcode's graphical debugger with an iOS app made with Rust?

Tags: ios, xcode, rust, lldb

I want to set breakpoints at arbitrary lines so I can step into, step over, print out LLDB messages, etc...

If there's no way, how hard would it be to implement something myself or to use an alternative IDE that can communicate with an iPhone?

Comment: Maybe there is a vscode plugin for IOS development?

Comment: I don't know about iOS, but on macOS it just works. Have you tried building Rust library with debug symbols and linking it into the iOS project?

Comment: It works with Xcode 9. But we just use Rust to write a multimedia SDK not the entire app like calling UIKit from Rust.

Comment: Were you able to get rust syntax highlighting?